# Using/adding delegation method and BackgroundWorker to my currently fully working program

Tags: c#, timer, backgroundworker, delegation

I've searched many topics but I can't seem to understand how to replace my existing methods with delegation+timer as I am currently using timer only. Also when adding `BackgroundWorker` to work with btng that moves the elevator down and opens the doors I get a multi-thread usage error stating that another thread is trying to insertdata in the .accdb where the main thread is recorded. I am adding the code which is not very long but fully working. Could someone give me a hint how to replace my existing methods with delegation and add one or two `BackgroundWorker`s to help the buttons that move the elevator and still keep the timers, please.

P.S. Do I need to share/change the database connection code in order to make it work with the backgroundworker? I'll add it if necessary. It's another couple of more lines..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace rewrite
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //variables

        int y_up = 63;
        int y_down = 376;
        int x_door_left_close = 74;
        int x_door_left_open = 12;
        int x_door_right_close = 139;
        int x_door_right_open = 200;

        bool go_up = false;
        bool go_down = false;

        bool arrived_G = false;
        bool arrived_1 = false;

        //object 
        SpeechSynthesizer reader = new SpeechSynthesizer();


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void timerliftdown_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (picturelift.Top <= y_down)
            {
                picturelift.Top += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                timerliftdown.Enabled = false;
                btnup.Enabled = true;
                btn1.Enabled = true;
                btnclose.Enabled = true;
                btnopen.Enabled = true;
                btndown.BackColor = Color.Red;
                btng.BackColor = Color.Red;

                dooropendown();
                arrived_G = true;

                picturelift.Image = global::rewrite.Properties.Resources.Inside_of_the_lift;
                displaypanel.Image = global::rewrite.Properties.Resources.G;
                displaytop.Image = global::rewrite.Properties.Resources.G;
                displaybottom.Image = global::rewrite.Properties.Resources.G;
            }
        }

        private void timerliftup_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (picturelift.Top >= y_up)
            {
                picturelift.Top -= 1;
            }
            else
            {

                timerliftup.Enabled = false;
                btndown.Enabled = true;
                btng.Enabled = true;
                btnclose.Enabled = true;
                btnopen.Enabled = true;
                btnup.BackColor = Color.Red;
                btn1.BackColor = Color.Red;

                dooropenup();
                arrived_1 = true;

                picturelift.Image = global::rewrite.Properties.Resources.Inside_of_the_lift;
                displaypanel.Image = global::rewrite.Properties.Resources._1;
                displaytop.Image = global::rewrite.Properties.Resources._1;
                displaybottom.Image = global::rewrite.Properties.Resources._1;
            }
        }

        private void dooropendown_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (doorleftdown.Left >= x_door_left_open && doorrightdown.Left <= x_door_right_open)
            {
                doorleftdown.Left -= 1;
                doorrightdown.Left += 1;
            }
            else
            {

                timerdooropendown.Enabled = false;

            }
        }

        private void timerdoorclosedown_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (doorleftdown.Left <= x_door_left_close && doorrightdown.Left >= x_door_right_close)
            {
                doorleftdown.Left += 1;
                doorrightdown.Left -= 1;
            }
            else
            {
                timerdoorclosedown.Enabled = false;

                if (go_up == true)
                {
                    picturelift.Image = global::rewrite.Properties.Resources.lift_transparent;
                    displaypanel.Image = global::rewrite.Properties.Resources.up;
                    displaytop.Image = global::rewrite.Properties.Resources.up;
                    displaybottom.Image = global::rewrite.Properties.Resources.up;

                    reader.Speak("Going up");

                    timerliftup.Enabled = true;
                    go_up = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private void dooropenup_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (doorleftup.Left >= x_door_left_open && doorrightup.Left <= x_door_right_open)
            {
                doorleftup.Left -= 1;
                doorrightup.Left += 1;
            }
            else
            {

                timerdooropenup.Enabled = false;

            }
        }

        private void timerdoorcloseup_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (doorleftup.Left <= x_door_left_close && doorrightup.Left >= x_door_right_close)
            {
                doorleftup.Left += 1;
                doorrightup.Left -= 1;
            }
            else
            {
                timerdoorcloseup.Enabled = false;

                if (go_down == true)
                {
                    picturelift.Image = global::rewrite.Properties.Resources.lift_transparent;
                    displaypanel.Image = global::rewrite.Properties.Resources.down;
                    displaytop.Image = global::rewrite.Properties.Resources.down;
                    displaybottom.Image = global::rewrite.Properties.Resources.down;

                    reader.Speak("Going down");

                    timerliftdown.Enabled = true;
                    go_down = false;
                }
            }
        }
        private void doorclosedown()
        {
            reader.Speak("doors closing");
            insertdata("door closing @Ground floor");
            timerdoorclosedown.Enabled = true;
            timerdooropenup.Enabled = false;
        }
        private void dooropendown()
        {
            reader.Speak("Ground floor, doors opening");
            insertdata("doors opening @Ground floor");
            timerdoorclosedown.Enabled = false;
            timerdooropendown.Enabled = true;
        }
        private void doorcloseup()
        {
            reader.Speak("doors closing");
            insertdata("Doors closing @First Floor");
            timerdoorcloseup.Enabled = true;
            timerdooropenup.Enabled = false;
        }
        private void dooropenup()
        {
            reader.Speak("First Floor, doors opening");
            insertdata("Doors Opening @First Floor");
            timerdoorcloseup.Enabled = false;
            timerdooropenup.Enabled = true;
        }
        private void going_up()
        {
            go_up = true;
            doorclosedown();
            btng.Enabled = false;
            btndown.Enabled = false;
            btnclose.Enabled = false;
            btnopen.Enabled = false;
            arrived_G = false;
            insertdata("Lift going up");
        }
        private void going_down()
        {
            go_down = true;
            doorcloseup();
            btn1.Enabled = false;
            btnup.Enabled = false;
            btnclose.Enabled = false;
            btnopen.Enabled = false;
            arrived_1 = false;
            insertdata("Lift going down");
        }

        private void btndown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnup.BackColor = Color.DarkCyan;
            going_up();
        }

        private void btnup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btndown.BackColor = Color.DarkCyan;
            going_down();
        }

        private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btn1.BackColor = Color.DarkCyan;
            going_up();
        }

        private void btng_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btng.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange;
            going_down();
        }

        private void btnclose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (arrived_G == true)
            {
                doorclosedown();
            }
            else if (arrived_1 == true)
            {
                doorcloseup();
            }
        }

        private void btnopen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (arrived_G == true)
            {
                dooropendown();
            }
            else if (arrived_1 == true)
            {
                dooropenup();
            }
        }

        private void btnalarm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnalarm.BackColor = Color.Green;
            reader.Speak("Emergency Stop. Please exit carefully.");
            insertdata("Emergency Stop!");
            timerliftdown.Enabled = false;
            timerliftup.Enabled = false;
            timerdooropendown.Enabled = true;
            timerdooropenup.Enabled = true;
            displaypanel.Image = global::rewrite.Properties.Resources.alarmbellbutton;
            displaytop.Image = global::rewrite.Properties.Resources.alarmbellbutton;
            displaybottom.Image = global::rewrite.Properties.Resources.alarmbellbutton;
        }
```

Comment: *"...to work with btng that moves the elevator down..."* what is the btng?

Comment: Makes the elevator go down the ground floor. Hoping I can use this/turn it into a delegate with a backgroundworker somehow
```private void btng_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            going_down();
        }
{private void going_down()
        {
            go_down = true;
            doorcloseup();
            btn1.Enabled = false;
            btnup.Enabled = false;
            btnclose.Enabled = false;
            btnopen.Enabled = false;
            arrived_1 = false;
            insertdata("Lift going down");
        }

Comment: From what I understand, the `btng` is a [`Button`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button).

Comment: I already did it friend . using this 
```
  this.bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            this.bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
            this.bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
            this.bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
            this.bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

            this.button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
```
and then i added the object senders for the EventArgs for the backgroundworker processes

Comment: lifecycles if you have found a solution to the problem, you could post it as an answer. Self-answering is [explicitly encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) on this site.